# Error: Can't resolve './app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\projects\Project-CMS\Project.Web\src'

Tags: angular, build

When I Create Build for my angular 5 Application I am getting the below error.

its working fine when I create build

```
ng build
```

it's showing error when I create buildproductionttion

```
ng build --prod
```

i am not using the ngfactory anywhere in my application.

> ERROR in ./src/main.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   './app/app.module.ngfactory' in
>   'C:\projects\Project-CMS\Project.Web\src' resolve
>   './app/app.module.ngfactory' in
>   'C:\projects\Project-CMS\Project.Web\src'   using description file:
>   C:\projects\Project-CMS\Project.Web\package.json (relative path:
>   ./src)
>       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration   after using description file:
>   C:\projects\Project-CMS\Project.Web\package.json (relative path:
>   ./src)
>       using description file: C:\projects\Project-CMS\Texakoma.Web\package.json (relative path:
>   ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory)
>         no extension
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           C:\projects\Project-CMS\Project.Web\src\app\app.module.ngfactory
>   doesn't exist
>         .ts
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           C:\projects\Project-CMS\Project.Web\src\app\app.module.ngfactory.ts
>   doesn't exist
>         .js
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           C:\projects\Project-CMS\Project.Web\src\app\app.module.ngfactory.js
>   doesn't exist
>         as directory
>           C:\projects\Project-CMS\Project.Web\src\app\app.module.ngfactory
>   doesn't exist
>   [C:\projects\Project-CMS\Project.Web\src\app\app.module.ngfactory]
>   [C:\projects\Project-CMS\Project.Web\src\app\app.module.ngfactory.ts]
>   [C:\projects\Project-CMS\Project.Web\src\app\app.module.ngfactory.js]
>   [C:\projects\Project-CMS\Project.Web\src\app\app.module.ngfactory] 
>   @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-66  @ multi ./src/main.ts

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Comment: updated package.json in question

Comment: Are you using e2e tests which include the use of browser variable?

Comment: i am not using them. is it creating the problem .?

Comment: No, was just to see if you were importing browser from a wrong place (like selenium o something like that)

Comment: Check this if it helps: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8036

Comment: can you post your app.component.ts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same error in angular 5. this works for me

```
ng build --prod --aot=false
```

**another solution**
I upgrade my ng version from 5.1.0 to version 5.1.1. it solve the problem without adding --aot=false option.

Answer (score 1):

I started getting this error after i used

```
ng update
```

and I resolved the issue by reverting my package.json to the previous version of angular,

I downgraded from 6.1.3 to 6.0.7

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Try the build by disabling aot and see if it works. Use ng build --prod --aot=false. If this works then you might want to refer to the link below. It looks like there is a bug, upgrading angular and/or cli should fix it.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8797